# Sybase ASE Errors - Getting ASA6525 and ASA6517

Tags: sap-ase

When attempting to insert a row into a table I get 2 errors - with one set of data I get ASA6525 contraint violation.  With a different set of data I get ASA6517 constraint violation.

```
ERROR: [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Constraint 'ASA6517' 
violated: Invalid value in table 'emp_def' Error Code: -1091
```

I have been trying to figure out what the issue is - with no real success.  The error only says invalid value in table with no guidance what value is not valid or how to find the answer.

Where do I look to find the details around these errors?  We are running ASE v16.

Comment: run `sp_helpconstraint emp_def` to get a list of constraints; this should show you the type/details of the constraints in question

Comment: My research suggested this same command.  However, when I try this I get an error "sp_helpconstraint not found error code: -265

Comment: something's fishy about your env; your error message mentions `SQL Anywhere`, the constraint name includes `ASA` which is an abbreviation for `Adaptive Server Anywhere` (another name for `SQL Anywhere`), and while I'd expect `SQL Anywhere` to state that `sp_helpconstraint` not found I would not expect this for `ASE`; have you tried running `sp_helpconstraint` via the (ASE) `isql` command line?